# performing click event without using onclick event

Tags: html, asp.net, button

I have a HTML button and i am just curious an wanna know whether its possible to call a codebehind method  without using onclick event

```
 <input type="button" value="Sig-In"  id="btnlogin"/>
```

Comment: sure using javascript/jquery ajax call you can call serverside method

Comment: which event you wanna fire?

Answer (score 1):

If the button does a post back, page events like Page_Load will be fired without even having a click event handler. Why can't you just use click event handler?

Answer (score -1):

you can use event load in javascript:

```
<input type="button" value="Sig-In"  id="btnlogin"/>
```

and javascript you use like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#btnlogin" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
        alert( "Load was performed." );
     });
 });
```

this is example in http://jsfiddle.net/YBS4r/2/

Comment: I would use click rather than load